# Meta tags are not showing up when scraped

Tags: gatsby, react-helmet

When I use react-helmet to construct meta tags for my [site](https://dev.wisedoc.net/how-to-write-a-resume/), it is showing up in the build version of it(public) but when I deploy to s3(cloud-front) and try to scrape it through bots in [metatags](https://metatags.io/) , it is not showing the meta tags. I tried one of the solutions provided here [#22206](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/22206#issuecomment-710591572) but it isn't still working. Later, I commented [here](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/22206#issuecomment-749510287) with the configurations I had.

Please help me out if you have any idea about this scenario! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was lying in s3 and cloud front configurations. Here are the changes

1. By changing cloudfront distribution origin to s3 bucket website endpoint
   [image]
2. Modifying bucket policy from cloudfront access only to all
   [image]